# Convert string array to typescript enum

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, enums

simple question there but I struggle to find an answer, all existing answers are for enum to array.

I wonder if there is a way to transform a string array:

```js
const arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

into the equivalent of

```js
type myType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

?

Comment: `type myType = typeof arr[number]`

Comment: Also, you were probably struggling since that's a union of strings, not an enum.

Comment: you need to do `const arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] as const` and `type myType = typeof arr[number]`